# My style doesn't working in PHP MVC project

Tags: php, css

I have a MVC project, wrote on PHP. Near the views, controllers etc. there is an assets/css/ with style.css. The code of the layout where I link is next:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css"/>
    <title> <?= $Title ?> </title>
</head>
<body>
<?include 'header.php'?>
<main class="container mt-3">
    <?= $Content ?>
</main>
<?include 'footer.php'?>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`$Title` and `$Content` are stored in the variables, made by extracting array of parameters in Template.php and using ob_start(); and including the required view. HTML code returns back, all how it was told to do by university's lector. The particular link for my own style `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css"/>` doesn't work while the bootstrap and Google Font (written in `style="..."` of element) do.

Is there any idea how to fix it? I moved it everywhere, but anyway it is ignored.

Comment: What do you see in the debug console of your browser? Does this resource return a 404 or any other error?

Comment: @JulienB. if there would be 404, i would be notifies as i have a simple view for that case, and there is no problem as debugger doesn't notifies me about errors

Comment: If you’re absolutely sure that it’s loading the css, then the next thing is to challenge your assumptions on how your html should interact with the css. I’ve seen people have non-unique ids and then wonder why things don’t work. Try putting your css right in the html template and see if it works there. If it does, you have a file loading problem. If it doesn’t, you have a misunderstanding about the css. It happens...

Comment: It appears I figured why it didn't work. It used to load older version of CSS, but when I try to read the .css file directly, it shows correct code, and so it works on the pages. Somehow, it works, so i just need to fill style and don't touch after the project's end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the browser from using a cached but out of date css file, attach a query string that changes when the file is changed.

```
<link href="/assets/css/style.css?<?=  filemtime( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/css/style.css" )  ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This signals the browser to use the new copy whenever it is changed.